# Возникла ошибка при работе с WWW-доменами

Tags: nginx, ispmanager

Купил сервер, была предустановлена панель ISPManager, через панель установил apache, nginx, php, mysql
При добавлении нового сайта через панель, выводится ошибка:
`Возникла ошибка при работе с WWW-доменами. Тест конфигурации web-сервера при сохранении файла '/etc/nginx/vhosts/www-root/facar.ru.conf' завершился неудачно: * Testing nginx configuration ...fail!`
Если отключить nginx, то сайт добавляется и работает

Пробовал удалять и по новой устанавливать nginx, перезагружал, как nginx, так и сервер полностью

Команда `sudo nginx -t` выдает

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok                                                                                                           
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: Логи isp смотрите.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev а где хранится логи? Смотрел /usr/local/mgr5/var/ispmgr.log, в нем ошибок нет

Comment: А зачем вам и апач, и нгинкс? По всей видимости ругается оно на апач.

Comment: @Sheridan Я в этом не сильно разбираюсь, но на предыдущем сервере стоял apache и nginx и все хорошо работало. Если не установлен nginx в настройках домена нет вкладки Оптимизация домена - возможности выбрать кэширование и сжатие

Comment: Попробуйте удалить апач и попробовать взлететь

Comment: Если не разбираетесь - обратитесь лучше в тех.поддержку хостинга - там помогут быстрее, в том числе исправят всё то, что вы уже успели сделать не правильно.

Comment: @Sheridan пробовал удалять и устанавливать по новой Apache и nginx, все равно ошибка

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Обратился в тех. поддержку, сказали ошибка "Некорректно создаются конфигурационные файлы виртуальных хостов" самое простое решение это переустановить ОС, тех.поддержка сама переустановила ОС и после установки nginx у них также вышла эта ошибка, сейчас разбираются

Comment: оно и без nginx должно работать, если не высоконагруженное

Comment: Обычно это происходит из-за апача, ибо они висят на одном порте. Попробуйте через service nginx start и глянуть логи ошибок